# Cyberoam becomes unresponsive

Tags: networking, firewall

Our client has a Cyberoam CR 50ia device that drops off the LAN at random times. The device's web interface cannot be reached, it loses internet connectivity, and it cannot be pinged over the LAN.

We updated the firmware from 10.01.2 build 133 to 10.01.2 build 158, however this did not help. In fact it dropped offline more often, so we reverted it back to 10.01.2 build 133.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this device? Are there some backend logs that can be investigated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It either has a duplicate MAC or is broken, or there is a device with a chatty NIC in its vicinity.  It could also be a bad switch, or a bad cable, or a sub-par cable.  If the latter, you could try forcing the NIC to 10mbit half duplex if the device supports this, and see if it works more reliably (but this may also indicate a bad NIC).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will investigate these things if needed. After another upgrade to the latest firmware 12 hours ago it has been stable ever since. Totally strange.